# String to Date Time Conversion in windows phone app

Tags: string, date, time, windows-phone

I am new to windows app development. I need to convert Date and Time available in String Format to dd/mm/yyyy and hh:mm format so that I can use it in setting the reminder.

thanks in advance......

Comment: `DateTime` in WP development is exactly the same as it is in any other .NET application.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `DateTime.Parse(string)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

string ss=DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();

For additional Information---
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolongdatestring(v=vs.110).aspx